# unable to get post object models in my template

Tags: javascript, django, json, response, alert

i have a student model with name,age,email fields.i have created a form StudentForm for this an create a view like this

```
def student(request):
form=Studentform(request.POST)
if request.method=='POST':

    if form.is_valid():
        stu=Student()
        stu.name=form.cleaned_data['name']
        stu.email=form.cleaned_data['email']
        stu.age=form.cleaned_data['age']
        stu.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')

else:
    form=Studentform()
return render_to_response('index.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

and here my index.html

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var student={{ stu_var }}
    alert("erer")
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>

   <form action="/index/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="alert(student)">
      </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

now i want that i creat a json response in my student view which hold all the values of student object and render it to my index.html at the time of posting so i can generate a alert like---> "Aditya SIngh, You have successfully submit the data". where Aditya SIngh would be name of student 
i m new with django.thanx in advance for ur pricious response

Comment: Your question is not clear. Anyway, i think that the form you are submitting itself contains the name of the student as a value. Just take that value using Javascript and produce your desired alert.

Comment: HttpResponseRedirect make a GET petition, you can send data to your index, what you can do is what the answer below says "make another view" or make an ajax POST to another view and show a fancybox on the same page that you are.

Answer (score 1):

So, you'd like to see the saved student data after it is successfully saved ...  You don't need javascript/json for that.

In your code, after you save the info, you redirect the user to the "index" view.  Instead, you might want to redirect to a "success!" page, where you show the info:

```
HttpResponseRedirect('/success/%d/' % stu.id)
```

So the existing view might look like:

```
def student(request):

    form=Studentform(request.POST)

    if request.method=='POST':

        if form.is_valid():

            stu=Student()
            stu.name=form.cleaned_data['name']
            stu.email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            stu.age=form.cleaned_data['age']
            stu.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/%d/' % stu.id)
        else:
            pass
            # return the half-completed form with the old data so the
            # user can make corrections
            # this "else" is not required, I just put it in here
            # to have a place to put this comment
            # and to show that this is another path that might be taken
            # through the code.

    else:
        # empty form for the user to fill out
        form=Studentform()

    return render_to_response('index.html',
        {'form':form},
        context_instance = RequestContext(request) )
```

And you would add a view (also the corresponding template and url entry) for the success page:

```
def success (request, id=None):

    stu = Student.objects.get (id = id)

    return render_to_response ('success.html',
        {'stu', stu},
        context_instance = RequestContext(request) )
```

If you really want an "alert" dialogue box, you can make an onLoad event for that.

If you want the alert dialogue box *and* the index page, then there is a problem.  The view can only return one thing, and you are already returning the index page.  You would have to somehow tell the index page which student to get info about, but the index page is not really designed for that (assuming you are using the "index" page as in the Django tutorials, a list of models with no form).

What a lot of web sites do is to put the newly created user on their profile page, if they successfully create an account.  That way they get confirmation that they have successfully logged in, and they are ready to do something useful instead of looking at a "success" page.

Or, they put the person on the main page of the site, but the person's login name is in the navbar.  This assumes that they have logged in as well as registered.